# junit test delete method with spring

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I made the following test method for delete method. I get 200 ok when test status , now I need to test that after calling the webservice ensure that the student was deleted I use this code to make that

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(s.getId().intValue()))
```

but get exception json can not be null or emty,Can anyone please help me how can i test delete method?

```
@Test
public void testDelete() throws Exception {
  Student s = data.getAll();
  ResultActions perform = mockMvc.perform(
      delete(studentWebservice.URL + "/{id}", m.getId()));
  perform.andDo(print())
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(s.getId().intValue()))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value(s.name));
}
```

method in service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void delete(@PathVariable Long id);
```

method implementation

```
@Override
public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
    repo.delete(id);
}
```

Comment: Does the delete method you're testing send back JSON in the response? Where is the code?

Comment: I edit the post and added delete method

Comment: Your method returns void. So the HTTP response body will be empty. And yet you're trying to parse it as JSON and extract an id and a name from it. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you help me how can i do it please?

Comment: The contract of the method is to delete the resource and return nothing. So mock the service in the controller test, and verify that its delete() method was called. Or, if it's an integration test and services are not mocked, send another request that GETs the resource, and check that you get a 404 (since the resource should have been deleted)

Answer (score 0):

Your service doesn't return anything on delete, so you can't check it in that way.
Make it return a json object like below.

```
@Override public Student delete(@PathVariable Long id {
    Student s = repo.get(id);
    repo.delete(id);
    return s;
}
```